# can you set socks5 proxy from Linux command line?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding, socks5

I've managed to set a socks5 proxy server from Linux towards another server like this :

`ssh -D 9090 -N -f user@192.168.76.102`
Then I changed the settings in mozilla browser to use the socks proxy, and it works, I can surf the internet. What I want do is to set this setting in Linux command line, so I can have access to the internet from there , like so : `wget www.google.com` .
First I tried editing the /etc/environmental file :

```
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:9090
```

But it doesn't work :

```
wget www.google.com 
Error parsing proxy URL socks5://127.0.0.1:9090: Unsupported scheme ‘socks5’.
```

Then I installed proxychains4 ,  and added in /etc/proxychains4.conf :

`socks5  127.0.0.1 9090`

But still doesn't work :

```
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.google.com
```

Do you have any ideas how I can make this work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool to test your SOCKS proxy settings. `wget` does not have built-in support for SOCKS, it has support for HTTP / HTTPS.

`curl` on the other hand has built-in support for SOCKS and thus you should use it instead.

See [man curl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/curl.1.html) for information and usage.

Comment: I used : ``` curl -x socks5h://localhost:9090 http://www.google.com/ -o output.curl ``` and it works, thank you